# redux.js:91 Uncaught Error: Expected the reducer to be a function

Tags: javascript, react-redux, es6-modules, reducers

Below is a piece of the code:
[image]

This is the error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'reducers' is your combined/root reducer, try this:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';

const store = createStore( reducers, compose( applyMiddleware( ReduxPromise )) )
```

and then:

```
<Provider store={ store } >
```